# jacobi identity implies flexible algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, associativity

I was looking in the wikipedia article about Non-associative Algebra and came across this interesting line:

> Each of the properties associative, commutative, anticommutative, Jordan identity, and Jacobi identity individually imply flexible.

It was quite [easy to find](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Commutative_implies_flexible) why the first three properties imply flexible algebra.
I was wondering about the last two (Jacobi and Jordan).
I went to look for the proof in [Schafer](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/25156/25156-pdf.pdf?session_id=f885ff1ee5b200968d45d42fc03be559b515b877) but either I missed it or it was given in terms I could not understand.

could someone give a proof similar to the commutative proof?

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm looking for proofs of the following statements:

1) given Jacobi identity prove flexible:

$
\forall x,y,z: (xy)z+(yz)x+(zx)y=0 \Rightarrow \forall x,y: x(yx)=(xy)x
$

2) given Jordan identity prove flexible:

$
\forall x,y: (xy)x^2=x(yx^2) \Rightarrow \forall x,y: x(yx)=(xy)x
$

EDIT 2:
OK, so it appears that Schafer does have a proof for the jordan identity implying flexiblity on chapter V. once I can understand it I hope I can write it here.

Comment: stackexchange did not allow more than two links, so here is the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-associative_algebra

Comment: Since it's not so commonly mentioned, it might be worth reminding readers that an algebra $(A, \cdot)$ is **flexible** iff $$a \cdot (b \cdot a) = (a \cdot b) \cdot a$$ for all $a, b \in A$.

Comment: The reference "Okubo 2005" in the wikipedia article only says that Lie algebras and Jordan algebras are flexible (because they are anticommutative and commutative, respectively). That flexibility follows from the Jacobi or Jordan *identities*, however, is a stronger claim. Perhaps the wikipedia article is mistaken?

Comment: maybe it is wrong. then I'd like to see a counter example.

Comment: @Blop Know any noncommutative nonanticommutative algebras satisfying the Jacobi identity? (I don't)

Comment: I have to admit i don't have much algebra knowledge, but from the why it is stated i assumed it is an easy proof. is it proved that no such algebras exist? maybe an example can be constructed just for the argument. I have to admit that when i posted this answer I thought I was just missing something...

Comment: @ebrahim Leibniz algebras (also called Loday algebras) are neither commutative or anticommutative and they do satisfy Jacobi.

Comment: Looking at the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_algebra it looks like they don't have to satisfy Jacobi. They satisfy the Leibniz identity, which is equivalent to the Jacobi identity in the presence of anticommutativity (i.e. when they are Lie algebras, which we already know are flexible).

Answer (score 1):

I've had troubles with this very question. This is an attempt to answer.

Both claims are false. You can even craft a counterexample yourself for 2) by chosing a field $F$ of $char(F)=2$. However if $char(F)\neq 2$, Schafer proved (be careful while checking the assumptions) this claim to be True, see [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2032791?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

For 1) there is a counterexample too. Consider the Algebra generated by $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ over a field $F$ with nonzero products given by $e_3e_1=e_2,\ e_3e_3=e_1$. Then for  any $x,y,z$ we have $(xy)z=0$, interchanging we conclude that $(xy)z+(yz)x+(zx)y=0+0+0=0$ but taking $v=e_1+e_2+e_3$ we must have $e_2=e_3(ve_3)\neq(e_3v)e_3=0$ hence the Algebra can not be flexible.